# fill a years worth of datetimes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I'm trying to fill datetimes for every minute of a year, in sql server.  I found the code below, which nicely fills all the dates for a year.  I was wondering if there's an easy way to modify to get datetimes filled down to the minute.

```
Code:

declare @datestart date = '2010-1-1',   @dateend date = '2016-10-31'

declare @days int = datediff(d,@datestart,@dateend)

select
    dateadd(d, number, @datestart)
from master..spt_values 
where type='p'
    and number<=@days
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: Not in the way you've done it with days. There are only 2048 records in spt_values (type='P'), which is fine for the 365 days in this example but will fall well short of the number of minutes in a year.

Comment: Use a while loop and `mi` or `n` instead of `d` in your `DATEADD()` function. You also need `DATETIME` datatypes rather than just `DATE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to extend your original attempt to handle the minutes. Depending on how often you intend to do this you may need to optimize your approach. I imagine that a simple loop is sufficient for your needs.

```
create table #minutes (dt datetime not null);
declare @datestart datetime = '2016-01-01 00:00', @dateend datetime = '2016-01-03 23:59';

while @datestart <= @dateend
begin
    insert into #minutes (dt)
    select dateadd(minute, number, @datestart)
    from master..spt_values 
    where
            type = 'p' and number between 0 and 1439
        and dateadd(minute, number, @datestart) <= @dateend;
    set @datestart = dateadd(minute, 1440, @datestart);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Numbers](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) table..

```
declare @startdate datetime
set @startdate='20160101'

;with cte(startdate)
as
(select @startdate
)
select b.*from cte c
cross apply
(
select dateadd(minute,n,c.startdate ) as minutes
from numbers n
where dateadd(minute,n,c.startdate) <= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, -1)) b
```

If you dont want numbers table,you can use recursive CTE like below..But this version is slow(Took 10 seconds on my system) and you may hit maxrecursion limit when you want to generate minutes for more than  years..

```
declare @startdate datetime
set @startdate='20160101'

;With Cte(startdate)
as
(
select @startdate
union all
select dateadd(minute,1,startdate)
from cte
where dateadd(minute,1,startdate)<=DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, -1)
)
select * from cte option(maxrecursion 0)
```

**Output of both versions:**

```
2016-01-01 00:01:00.000
2016-01-01 00:02:00.000
```

Comment: Numbers table?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @DavidTansey:  Its just numbers from 1 to some very big number,but very helpfull for some many operations..see this link..http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable

Comment: A numbers table acts as a auxiliary data store by which all other numeric entities (E.G. integers, decimals, dates, bytes, GUIDs, bitwise-ASCII manipulation) can be quickly calculated and populated. Think of it as it pertains to mathematical set functions.

I first learned about this from Joe Celko. (He has a book covering auxiliary and temporal tables.)

A table with dates and times for look-ups and data manipulation (such as providing holes where data is missing from other tables through left outer joins) would be another example of an Auxiliary table.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go recursive:

```
declare @datestart date = '2010-1-1',   @dateend date = '2016-10-31'

;with cte as (select cast(@datestart as datetime) as d union all
              select dateadd(MINUTE,1,d) from cte where d<@dateend)
select * 
  from cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**OUPUT**

```
   d
    2010-01-01 00:00:00.000
    2010-01-01 00:01:00.000
    2010-01-01 00:02:00.000
    2010-01-01 00:03:00.000
    2010-01-01 00:04:00.000
    2010-01-01 00:05:00.000
    ...
    2016-10-30 23:58:00.000
    2016-10-30 23:59:00.000
    2016-10-31 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     declare @start datetime='1/1/2016 0:0:0' 
     declare @end datetime 
     set @end=DATEADD(year,1,@start)

    ;with cte
    as
    (
    select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.name ) AS Row 
    from master..spt_values  a, master..spt_values  b
    )

    select cte.Row , DATEADD(minute,cte.Row,@start ) curr
    from cte
    where DATEADD(minute,cte.Row,@start ) < @end
```

Result:

```
    1   2016-01-01 00:01:00.000
    2   2016-01-01 00:02:00.000
    3   2016-01-01 00:03:00.000
    4   2016-01-01 00:04:00.000
    5   2016-01-01 00:05:00.000
    6   2016-01-01 00:06:00.000
    7   2016-01-01 00:07:00.000
    8   2016-01-01 00:08:00.000
    9   2016-01-01 00:09:00.000
    ....

    ...
    527031  2016-12-31 23:51:00.000
    527032  2016-12-31 23:52:00.000
    527033  2016-12-31 23:53:00.000
    527034  2016-12-31 23:54:00.000
    527035  2016-12-31 23:55:00.000
    527036  2016-12-31 23:56:00.000
    527037  2016-12-31 23:57:00.000
    527038  2016-12-31 23:58:00.000
    527039  2016-12-31 23:59:00.000
```

and you can get more for extra years :) (if needed) , or may be in second :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution with Recursion is very nice, but that should be faster:

```
;WITH Pass0 as (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1)) as A(C)),
  Pass1 as (select 1 as C from Pass0 as A, Pass0 as B),--16 rows
  Pass2 as (select 1 as C from Pass1 as A, Pass1 as B),--256 rows  
  Pass3 as (select 1 as C from Pass2 as A, Pass2 as B),--65536 rows
  Pass4 as (select 1 as C from Pass3 as A, Pass3 as B),--65536 rows
  Pass5 as (select 1 as C from Pass4 as A, Pass4 as B),-- 16 Mln Records 
  Numbers AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 as Numbers FROM Pass5)
SELECT DATEADD(mi,Numbers,@datestart) as Next_Minute 
FROM Numbers
WHERE Numbers <= DATEDIFF(minute,@datestart,@dateend);
```